# Does Android use a custom windowing system?

Tags: android, opengl-es, window, x11

As far as I know Android is not using X11 or is it? If it isn't, does anyone know how exactly EGL binds to some kind of a native window as is the usual case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Android uses its own compositor called SurfaceFlinger.

Comment: Thanks R! That's exactly what I hoped for - an official point!